# Checkmarx Java fix for Log Forging -sanitizing user input

Tags: java, spring-boot, spring-mvc, checkmarx, secure-coding

Can anyone suggest the proper sanitization/validation process required for the courseType variable in the following getCourses method. I am using that variable to write in a log file.

I've tried HtmlUtils.HtmlEscape() but didn't get expected results.

Thanks!

```
@RequestMapping(value = "/retriveCourses", method = RequestMethod.GET)
@ResponseBody
public List<Course> getCourses(@RequestParam(value = "courseType", required = false) String courseType) {

}
```

Comment: Can you add the part of the code where you write to the log?

Comment: Hi..thanks for the reply. I am writing the @RequestParam to the log as follows -logger.info("Course Type is "+HtmlUtils.HtmlEscape(courseType)). This enabling log forging.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

it seems like the Checkmarx tool is correct in this case.

A "Log Forging" vulnerability means that an attacker could engineer logs of security-sensitive actions and lay a false audit trail, potentially implicating an innocent user or hiding an incident.

While using `htmlEscape` will escape some special characters:

- `&amplt;` represents the `<` sign.
- `&ampgt;` represents the `>` sign.
- `&ampamp;` represents the `&` sign.
- `&ampquot;` represents the `"` mark.

It will not escape or remove new-line/EOL/tab characters that must be avoided in order to keep logs integrity.

The best practice recommendations to avoid log forging are:

1. Make sure to replace all relevant dangerous characters. example:

   `cleanInput = input.replace('\t', '-').replace('\n', '-').replace('\r', '-');`
2. Validate all input, regardless of source. Validation should be based on a whitelist. Accept only data fitting a specified structure, rather than reject bad patterns. Check for: Data type, Size, Range, Format, Expected values.

Hopefully, that solves your problem.

Answer (score 6):

1. Have a look at the [Logging - OWASP Cheat Sheet Series](https://cheatsheetseries.owasp.org/cheatsheets/Logging_Cheat_Sheet.html) in the section 'Event Collection'
2. The best encoder still  [OWASP Java Encoder](https://wiki.owasp.org/index.php/OWASP_Java_Encoder_Project) => Solve the 2. of @yaloner
3. There is also a project at OWASP To help you to deal withs log injections [OWASP Security Logging](https://wiki.owasp.org/index.php/OWASP_Security_Logging_Project) => Solve the 1. of @yaloner

Have a look at them will solve the issue

Comment: Direct links to the projects in question: https://github.com/OWASP/owasp-java-encoder/ and https://github.com/javabeanz/owasp-security-logging